# How to make safer AddCallback() - function for different events in object

Tags: c++, events, callback

I have `AddCallback()` witn second parameter `int`. But how to reduce the
possibility of transmission of incorrect `type` from client code? What is a good style for this situation?
*note:* type is incorrect if it not equal `mouseDown` `mouseUp` `mouseHover`  `mouseLeave`

```
const int  mouseDown = 0;
const int  mouseUp = 1;
const int  mouseHover = 2;
const int  mouseLeave = 3;

class Widget
{
public:
    ...
    bool AddCallback(void (*func)(Widget*), const int type);
protected:
    std::vector<void (*)(Widget*)>  funcsDown;
    std::vector<void (*)(Widget*)>  funcsUp;
    std::vector<void (*)(Widget*)>  funcsHover;
    std::vector<void (*)(Widget*)>  funcsLeave;
    ...
};
```

Comment: what mean incorrect type?

Comment: if (type > 3) || (type < 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++11, you should use a strongly-typed enum:

```
enum class mouseAction { mouseDown = 0, mouseUp = 1, mouseHover = 2, mouseLeave = 3 };

bool AddCallback(void (*func)(Widget*), const mouseAction type);
```

With C++03, you could still use an enum and provide a second overload to make calls using an integer be turned into a linker error:

```
enum mouseAction { mouseDown = 0, mouseUp = 1, mouseHover = 2, mouseLeave = 3 };

// implement this method (here or somewhere else)
bool AddCallback(void (*func)(Widget*), const mouseAction type);

// but only declare this one:
bool AddCallback(void (*func)(Widget*), const int type);
```

if you call it like this:

```
myWidget.AddCallback( &foo, mouseDown ); // works
myWidget.AddCallback( &foo, 42 ); // linker error
```

Comment: thanx. but i must write in 2008 visual studio - it's not c++11, yes? can i find smth like this in boost?

Comment: @hoody Why not? It solves the problem: Catch the error. Compile-time error would of course be preferable to the link-time error, but still better than run-time errors.

Comment: i agree with you, but version for c++11 much nicer